# Write a PL/SQL procedure with no parameters Ins_Job that inserts new record in table JOBS

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Insert_Job AS
    v_job_id VARCHAR2(10) := 'HR_Assistant';
    v_job_title VARCHAR2(35) := 'HRessourcesAssistant';
    v_Min_Salary NUMBER(22):= 400;
    v_max_salary NUMBER (22):= 5000;
  
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO OEHR_JOBS (JOB_ID, JOB_TITLE,MIN_SALARY,MAX_SALARY)
    VALUES (v_job_id, v_job_title, v_Min_Salary, v_max_salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('Insertion OK');
End;
```

> Write a PL/SQL procedure with no parameters Insert_Job that inserts a new record in the table JOBS: - Job Id: Assistant - Job title: HRessources Assistant - Min Salary: 400 - Max Salary: 5000 The procedure should print a message to the user to inform him about the insertion status (success/ Error). Call the procedure and take a screenshot of the output in both cases.

This is what I try and it doesn't work any help please? It created the procedure but no data into the table, an also when I call it it shows me an error. I'm usnig APEX ORACLE HERE IS THE ERROR MESSAGE BELOW

ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00905: object WKSP_ELIASHOME.INSERT_JOB is invalid
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 626
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 612
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1749

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Did you enable output? If not, run `set serveroutput on` before calling the procedure. On a second thought, did you **call** the procedure at all? Code you posted just creates it; you should execute it, right? `begin insert_job; end;`

Comment: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "WKSP_ELIASHOME.INSERT_JOB1", line 2
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


1. begin insert_job1; end;  it showed me this error .

Comment: Dale k, it creates the procedure but in the table there is no data. and also when I call it it showed me an error .ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "WKSP_ELIASHOME.INSERT_JOB1", line 2 ORA-06512: at line 1 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read your error message: `numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`
This mean your length is too small.
In your code:

```
 v_job_id VARCHAR2(10) := 'HR_Assistant';
```

It was because length `'HR_Assistant'` is longer then 10

Try to change lenght `v_job_id` into:

```
v_job_id VARCHAR2(12) := 'HR_Assistant';
```

Or you can remove some character, into:

```
v_job_id VARCHAR2(10) := 'Assistant';
```

Or, maybe you must check first length from column `JOB_ID` in table `OEHR_JOBS`

Sorry if my english bad and I don't really familiar with PLSQL.